# Para describir alguien que está muy confundido

Tags: palabras-raras

¿Que otras palabras coloridas existen para describir a alguien que ha quedado fuera de si por una sorpresa? A mi me gustan *patidifuso* y *boquiabierto*.

Answer (score 11):

"**estupefacto**" me parece bastante contundente y de uso general, aunque quizás no tan "colorida". Igualmente correcta es "**atónito**"

Más informales (quizás más coloridas) serían: "**turulato**" (no se usa mucho) y "**patitieso**" (esta me suena algo más común que "patidifuso").

Comment: Está perdido, es un término coloquial, sin embargo aplica.

Comment: Sí, pero "aplica" es un anglicismo :-)

Comment: No no, estoy diciendo que "está perdido" aplica en este caso, aún siendo un término coloquial

Comment: Sí, y yo estoy diciendo que el uso que estás dando a la palabra "aplicar" en tu comentario es incorrecto, es un anglicismo. http://www.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=3L5ZwRJxDDXX29dzfDes

Comment: @leonbloy Podrías por favor revisar el enlace de tu comentario ya que no funciona y me gustaría leer porque ese uso particular del verbo "aplicar" es anglicismo. Gracias.

Comment: Parece que el uso, en este caso, no es un anglicismo. De acuerdo con el DLE: "8. intr. Am. Tener validez o relevancia para algo".

Answer (score 6):

En el diccionario ofrecen también "pasmado", a mí me gusta mucho.

Answer (score 5):

**anonadado** también aplica, aunque tampoco es de uso común

Comment: Yo conozco `anonadado`. ¿Es `anodadado` lo que querias escribir? Si la respuesta es si, ¿donde se usa?

Comment: si, ha de ser anonadado.

Comment: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=anonadado

es de esas palabras aliteradas que siempre me confunde :)

Answer (score 4):

No soy nativo, y por eso igual no te suena tan colorido como a mi, pero siempre me ha gustado *atontado*, y la idea que conlleva que algo ha dejado a la persona K.O., casí groggy, y sin poder hablar, ni siquiera pensar.

Comment: Yo no usaría "atontado" en ese concepto, al menos en mi región (sur de España), no se usa con el significado que describe Rodrigo

Answer (score 3):

Estoy de acuerdo con todos los sinónimos que se han dado. Algunos de ellos son muy buenos, aunque es cierto que son bastante formales y raramente usados en una conversación coloquial...

Me gustaría añadir algunos ejemplos más vulgares y que son muy usados en lenguaje coloquial (al menos en España), aunque no estoy seguro que respondan al perfil de palabras *coloridas*:

> **mudo**: "*Cuando conocí el Estadio Azteca me quedé **mudo***".
>
> **flipado**: "*Me dieron la noticia y me quedé **flipado***".

Algunos otros términos vulgares que también he oído como sinónimos en ciertos contextos podrían ser:

> "*Se quedó **pillado** / **tieso** / **helado** / **seco** / **tonto** / **parvo** con la sorpresa*".

Comment: Bueno, pero flipado no es mas que un anglicismo, verdad?

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez, `flipar` sí proviene del inglés `to flip`, pero está actualmente incluido en el diccionario de la RAE. Simplemente lo incluyo como una opción añadida a todas las buenas respuestas que ya tenías, y que además es tremendamente utilizada en el lenguaje coloquial en España...

Comment: Flipar está muy extendido.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a aportar una opción que aún no se ha añadido:

**ojiplático**: tener los ojos como platos o muy abiertos a causa de una sorpresa o asombro. Sinónimo de atónito, sorprendido, asombrado, pasmado, boquiabierto, patidifuso o alucinado

Comment: No está en el DRAE pero me parece fabulosa, la voy a usar.

Comment: Efectivamente, a día de hoy aún no está aceptada, pero se trata de una palabra correcta y de uso bastante frecuente, con lo que no me sorprendería que acabase siendo aceptada en futuras revisiones.